# Do we have a version of Grönwall lemma for $t<b$?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-integral, integral-inequality

Let $y(\cdot)$ be a continuous mappings defined on $[a,b]$ and $K\in (0,+\infty]$ a constant. An application of the Grönwall lemma is the following simple case: if we have for all $t\in[a,b]$
$$y(t)\leq K + \int_a^ty(s) ds ,$$
then we will have for all $t\in [a,b]$
$$y(t)\leq K e^{\int_a^tds}=Ke^{(t-a)}.
$$
My question is that do we still have such result if we change the order of the integral $\int_a^t ds$ to $\int_t^b ds$ in other words do we have the following implication:
$$\forall t\in [a,b]\; \;\;\; y(t)\leq K + \int_t^by(s) ds \implies \forall t\in [a,b]\; \;\;\;  y(t)\leq K e^{\int_t^bds}=Ke^{(b-t)}.$$

Comment: $t\to -t$ and see how it affects the inequality.

Comment: the problem is that we re not sure that $-t \in [a,b]$ , unless the interval is symetrical

Comment: Change signs everywhere to match the new $t$, of course.

Answer (score 2):

By taking : $z(t)=y(-t)$ for all $t\in [-b,-a]$, and changing the measure $ds=-d\tau$ we obtain
$$z(t)\leq K+\int_{-b}^t z(\tau)d\tau $$
and then by applying the classic Gronwall lemma we get that :
$$z(t)\leq Ke^{t+b} \;\; \forall t\in [-b,-a],$$
in other words
$$y(t)\leq Ke^{b-t} \;\; \forall t\in [a,b]$$